# Как преобразовать время в миллисекунды текущего дня на kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Изучаю разработку приложений на котлин и столкнулся с небольшой проблемой: не знаю, как преобразовать время в миллисекунды. К примеру, есть следующая переменная:

```kotlin
val dateformat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss")
val date = LocalTime.parse("16:00:00", dateformat)
```

Каким образом можно перевести это время в миллисекунды?

Comment: я пытался найти информацию, но ничего не нашел. Везде все на джаве, а когда пытаюсь подобное использовать в котлин, то этого в основном просто нет.

Comment: @Flamer, классы, которые вы используете `java.time.LocalTime` и `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` — они из мира Java. Они используются в Котлин точно так же, как и в Java.

Comment: Уточните в вопросе, вам нужно время в миллисекундах от начала дня или с начала эпохи (1 января 1970 года)? Если второе, то укажите также в вопросе дату и часовой пояс.

Comment: "Везде все на джаве, а когда пытаюсь подобное использовать в котлин, то этого в основном просто нет" -- эээ, пример можно увидеть?

Comment: @Vadik нужно время от начала дня.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja https://overcoder.net/q/57525/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-android

Comment: И что в этом коде невозможного? https://pl.kotl.in/FjJOD7k3I

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Получите время в наносекундах от начала дня и поделите на 1 000 000, получится время в миллисекундах:

```kotlin
date.toNanoOfDay() / 1000 / 1000
```

Вывод:

```
57600000
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Очень помогли, даже смешно, что сам не догадался до такого решения)

Comment: Эээ. Время в миллисекундах подразумевает юникс-время, а не количество (милли)секунд после последней полуночи.

Comment: В вопросе не было речи про unix time, там только LocalTime, без указания даты и часового пояса

Comment: Автор указал в вопросе, что ему нужны миллисекунды с начала текущего дня. 16 часов это 57600000 миллисекунд.